# SQL Server: Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I've just put in a request for our storage engineers to add more physical space for the LUN with tempdb. In this case, it was definitely needed. However, I'm disturbed by the SCOM report which flagged tempdb as using a 'DEFAULT' filegroup.

Can anyone clarify for me what 'DEFAULT' means in this context, since we don't have a filegroup called 'DEFAULT'?  We have a single filegroup for tempdb called 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: The primary filegroup is the default (where new stuff goes), unless you add another filegroup and make it the default.

Comment: Thanks sp_BlitzErik ! :) I guess I am muddled about this message because SCOM usually reports on the user databases we have for PRIMARY as PRIMARY, rather than DEFAULT.

Comment: I agree with you, i'd expect to see 'PRIMARY' since the DB name is also quoted--it makes it seem like this is the literal filegroup name versus, perhaps, the flag for is_default in sys.filegroups